# Hibernate joining two table and producing json response in spring restful webservice?

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, hibernate

> **I have two table**
>
> ***Category***

[image]

> ***Events***

[image]

> In table `Category` first five `category_name` is the main
>   category.according to those five i have to fetch the result.for
>   example if user giving `1` as the input first i need to sort `category_id`
>   who have `parent_category_id 1` in `Category table`.in this example i will
>   get the `category_id 6,7,8,9,10` because they have `parent_category_id 1`.
>
> Next , see in `Events table` also i have a field with name
>   `category_id`. i have the result from `Category` with `category_id` ie
>   , category_id `6,7,8,9,10`.
>
> I have to fetch all records from `Events table` whose `category_id`
>   matching from the result that we got from `Category table`.

***Confusion ?????????***

> See below my snap shot with query and result

[image]

> This result i got because in my `Event table` only have records with
>   `category_id 6 and 7`.
>
> My query is doing his job,

```
SELECT * FROM category c  inner join `events` e on e.category_id=c.category_id where c.parent_category_id=1;
```

> The problem is i have to integrate the query with `hibernate` and should
>   respond my `spring restful web service` with the `json` format follows
>   towards client.
>
> If the user giving input parameter as `1`
>
> Output should be json follows or in any standard format like that

```
Events {

    Infotech[
    {event_id:1,event_name:java_workshop},{event_id:2,event_name:java_workshop},......
            ],
    Socia[
    {event_id:1,event_name:java_workshop},{event_id:2,event_name:java_workshop},...
            ],......
    }
```

> I done simple json conversions in spring by adding json library with
>   spring restful web service.
>
> Now , just hold the json conversion and please help me to fetch
>   records like i mentioned ?

***And so far my codes***

> **Events entity class for hibernate mapping**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * The persistent class for the user database table.
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Events implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private int eventId;

    @Column(name = "event_name")
    private String eventName;

    @Column(name = "event_description")
    private String eventDescription;

    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "is_trending_event")
    private Integer isTrendingEvent;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(int eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String getEventDescription() {
        return eventDescription;
    }

    public void setEventDescription(String eventDescription) {
        this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
    }

    public Integer getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public Integer getIsTrendingEvent() {
        return isTrendingEvent;
    }

    public void setIsTrendingEvent(Integer isTrendingEvent) {
        this.isTrendingEvent = isTrendingEvent;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

> **Category entity**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * The persistent class for the user database table.
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = "parent_category_id")
    private Integer parentCategoryId;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Integer getParentCategoryId() {
        return parentCategoryId;
    }

    public void setParentCategoryId(Integer parentCategoryId) {
        this.parentCategoryId = parentCategoryId;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }

}
```

> **Fetch category method**

```
public List<Object[]> getCategoryList(int id) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        List<Object[]> groupList = null;
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Category c  inner join Events e on e.categoryId=c.categoryId where c.parentCategoryId= :id");
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            groupList = query.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return groupList;
    }
```

> How i should write the HQL query ? and Send back the result to client
>   in standard json format using spring restful web service ? Help me friends.

Comment: **Now , just hold the json conversion and please help me to fetch records like i mentioned ?**: Can you reduce your question to the core only so it becomes answerable?

Comment: In fact i have to get a lead for both the trouble ie , json conversion and HQL as well .. if you know any of these please help me with that..

Answer (score 0):

1. Dealing with HQL directly is not that nice. You might wanna look into [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) or [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) to help you with creating type-safe queries.
2. For your JSON conversion, you could for example look into [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18865015/5127499) or create a wrapping class, that maps your Category entities with the associated Events and use one of the many tutorials out there, like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/).