# Hibernate joining two table and fetch all records?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

> I have two entity class Category and Events.I need to join both the tables and fetch all records which matching the given condition

***My sql query for this***

```
SELECT * FROM category c  inner join `events` e on e.category_i=c.category_id where c.parent_category_id=1;
```

***How i can convert this sql query to hql and fetch the data ? I tried below but not getting the result ? Am very new to hibernate***

> **Events entity class for hibernate mapping**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * The persistent class for the user database table.
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Events implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private int eventId;

    @Column(name = "event_name")
    private String eventName;

    @Column(name = "event_description")
    private String eventDescription;

    @Column(name = "category_i")
    private Integer categoryI;






    public Integer getCategoryI() {
        return categoryI;
    }

    public void setCategoryI(Integer categoryI) {
        this.categoryI = categoryI;
    }

    @Column(name = "is_trending_event")
    private Integer isTrendingEvent;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(int eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String getEventDescription() {
        return eventDescription;
    }

    public void setEventDescription(String eventDescription) {
        this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
    }



    public Integer getIsTrendingEvent() {
        return isTrendingEvent;
    }

    public void setIsTrendingEvent(Integer isTrendingEvent) {
        this.isTrendingEvent = isTrendingEvent;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

> **Category entity**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * The persistent class for the user database table.
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = "parent_category_id")
    private Integer parentCategoryId;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="events", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="category_i"))
    private Events events;

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Integer getParentCategoryId() {
        return parentCategoryId;
    }

    public void setParentCategoryId(Integer parentCategoryId) {
        this.parentCategoryId = parentCategoryId;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }

}
```

> **Fetch category method**

```
public List<Object[]> getCategoryList(int id) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        List<Object[]> groupList = null;
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("select e from Category e inner join e.events where e.parentCategoryId=1");
            //query.setParameter("id", id);
            groupList = query.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return groupList;
    }
```

Comment: You can use hibernate criteria and there is an property for fetch join.

Comment: @Darshan kindly , please help me to do this. :(

Comment: Your mapping is wrong, you are thinking JDBC not hibernate, you are mapping objects not ids. In your `Event` you should have a `Category` object instead of an id.

Comment: if you dont mind please provide the answer for this so that i can understand the way of mapping clearly .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to think in terms of Java objects when using [ORM](http://hibernate.org/orm/what-is-an-orm/) tools.

From your question I think the query that you're trying to write will look something like:

```
public List<Category> getCategoryList(int id) {
    List<Category> groupList;
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select c from Category c join fetch c.events where c.parentCategory.categoryId = 1");
    //query.setParameter("id", id);
    groupList = query.list();
    return groupList;
}
```

One of the benefits of using an ORM is that it works out the full join query for you.

For this to work you need to update your class model as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private int eventId;

    @Column(name = "event_name")
    private String eventName;

    @Column(name = "event_description")
    private String eventDescription;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_i")
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "is_trending_event")
    private Integer isTrendingEvent;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    ...

}
```

and

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_category_id")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
    private List<Event> events;

    ...

}
```

Comment: This is my sql query `SELECT * FROM category c  inner join events e on e.category_i=c.category_id where c.parent_category_id=1;` the why i need to join  `parent_category_id`  in Category  entity ? can you please explain ?

Comment: You need to think about what data `SELECT * FROM category c inner join events e` is returning and how that maps back on to your java objects. It looks like you're looking for all `Event` objects and their associated `Category` where the category's parent has `categoryId = 1`?

Comment: for more details about tables and data fetching please give a look at the question i have asked and i didn't got an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476416/hibernate-joining-two-table-and-producing-json-response-in-spring-restful-webser

Comment: based upon your comment I've updated the solution to return `Category` objects that contains a populated collection of `Event` objects, which will map directly to the JSON that you're after. Note that I updated the `Category` model as well as the query.

Comment: U can see in my `getCategoryList` method with return type `List<Object[]>`..is it appropriate ?

Comment: `getCategoryList` should return `List<Category>`

Comment: by doing that will i get the datas from both the table like mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476416/hibernate-joining-two-table-and-producing-json-response-in-spring-restful-webser ?

Comment: Each `Category` in the list will contain it's own `List<Event>` member containing the associated `Event`s.

Comment: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize Exception

Comment: Added `getCategoryList` that does not swallow exceptions so we can check the query

Comment: i tried by editing the query.but scenario is same..can u say what is the problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83720/discussion-between-steve-c-and-stella).

Comment: @Steve +1 for your effort :)

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate is about mapping objects and the relations, however you are mapping simple id fields.

In your `Events` class you have the followingL

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Events implements Serializable { 

    @Column(name = "category_i")
    private Integer categoryI;

}
```

However it should be a `Category` instead of an `Integer`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Events implements Serializable { 

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "category_i")
    private Category category;

}
```

Then in your `Category` you should add the `mappedBy` field to the `@ManyToOne` on the `events` field and remove the `@JoinColumn`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
    private Events events;
}
```

The same applies to the `parentCategoryId` of the `Category` class.

Now that you have your mapping corrected you should be able to write the query as you wanted to.

Comment: So? The column name can still be there, just add the annotation. I strongly suggest a read on JPA and how it works. It is about mapping objects to your database structure. Use the technology as intended, you are working around it.

Comment: can you please explain Where we are doing the functionality of on keyword here?

Comment: `@ManyToOne(mappedBy="category")` showing error canot find symbol.have you meaned `OneToMany` ?

Comment: Yes I do.. Typo fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the job:

```
from Category as c
inner join c.events as e
where c.parentCategoryId = 1
```

Plus you seem to have a typo (missing "d" at the end) here:

`@JoinColumn(name="category_i"))`

Comment: @JoinColumn(name="category_i")) this is actually the column name for join in event table .i updated the event entity.not missed that.

Comment: Showing the error ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Unknown column 'category0_1_.events_event_id' in 'field list' when using this

Answer (score 0):

Ty this below code

```
public List<Object[]> getCategoryList(int id) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {


        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.createCriteria(Catagory.class)
        .setFetchMode("events", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("parentCatagoryId", 1))
        .list();

}
```

Hope this stuff works.

Comment: In this where we are mentioning which columns we need to join in my case i have to join category table 'category_id' and events table  'category_i' (Not primary key) .

Comment: ie , category c  inner join `events` e on e.category_i=c.category_id

Comment: There we no need to define which column bases we are joining ..we already define on bean definition.

Comment: can you please explain Where we are doing the functionality of `on` keyword here?

Comment: On setFectchMode property.