# Join two tables in hibernate sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate

I have Two tables in my system, the table request and table service.
The table service is connected to a request, it has its id.
I like to join two tables in request business class using hibernate, like this sql command:

```
select * from request r INNER JOIN  service s  ON s.request_id = r.id  WHERE s.is_last_service=1 and s.expiration_date>'2015-12-15';
```

How can i make this query  string for hibernate?

Comment: Use entity names in place of table names and use attribute names in place of column names. check documentation for further functions and other facilities provided by Hibernate

Comment: check this link
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/

Comment: Please show your entity classes

Comment: Similar question is already answered. Please look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509568/hibernate-joining-two-table-and-fetch-all-records?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509568/hibernate-joining-two-table-and-fetch-all-records?rq=1)