# How do I get JSON data from two tables using joins in Hibernate?

Tags: java, json, hibernate

`select a.empname,b.dname from employee a, department b where a.deptid=b.deptid`

Employee table contains `empid,empname` & `deptid`

Department tables contains `deptid` & `dname`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate joining two table and fetch all records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509568/hibernate-joining-two-table-and-fetch-all-records)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. You need a DTO to store the data and send it as JSON to frontend.

```
@Query("new com.example.service.model.search.SearchDTO" 
            +"(e.empname, d.dname) "
            + "from department d "
            + "join d.deptid e "
            + "where e.id=?1")
    public List<SearchDTO> findByIdEmployee (Long idEmployee );
```

Possible DTO structure:

```
public class SearchDTO {

    String EnpName;
    String DepName;

    public SearchDTO(String EnpName, String DepName) {
        this.EnpName = EnpName;
        this.DepName = DepName;
    }

    public String getEnpName() {
        return EnpName;
    }

    public void setEnpName(String EnpName) {
        this.EnpName = EnpName;
    }

    public String getDepName() {
        return DepName;
    }

    public void setDepName(String DepName) {
        this.DepName = DepName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some change in hql join.
For hql join we use classess insted of tables
if you have classes Employee and Department.
You can use query like

`select a.empname,b.dname from Employee as a
        left outer join Employee.department as b`

where empname, dname and department are fields of Employee,Department and Employee class.

Above query will return List you have to handle it properly.
Then convert this list to json object

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do,

1. HQL
2. One to One mapping.
3. Native Query using hibernate.

Best to Use : One to One mapping.

Refer : https://github.com/Roshanmutha/hibernate-samples/blob/master/R6_One_To_One_Mapping/src/main/java/entity/User.java